# I get ##[error]No code coverage results were found to publish. when trying to publish my create-react-app code-coverage in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, jestjs, code-coverage, create-react-app, cobertura

I am trying to publish code coverage from my create-react-app in Azure devOps  even though the coverage is generated when I run test locally I get the following error In azure pipeline when trying to publish the coverage "##[error]No code coverage results were found to publish." find the screenshots of my pipeline config  and the error. have being on this for two days now a working solution would greatly be appreciated.

files in the coverage folder:

```
 Coverage
    lcov-report(folder)
    clover.xml
    cobertura-coverage.xml
    coverage-final.json
    lcov.info
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J6tRN0RfYWtfc-cJ64Itxwnmlqe8c-BH/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-IKWETw2tuXexbk36VPOVpYRD6bCVYf/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sY6qBc1xEroCfOF3yt6ORbAXPPkr04JE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please list files in the folder where you suppose to have coverage file.

Comment: I modified the post and listed the files